# SSIS "Execute Package task" in a "for each file" loop failed when loading large number of small files

Tags: sql-server, ssis, out-of-memory, buffer, flat-file

I have a SSIS package including an "**Execute Package Task**" (**ExecuteOutOfProcess** = False) to be executed as many times as there are files in a specific folder.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGVQG.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YlU0.png)

The sub package task is a very simple Package including a DFT that loads data from flat file (.csv) into SQL Server Table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vKXM.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoyMd.png)

It runs correctly with limited number of files, but now I have to load more than 2.000 files (each one has less than 1000 rows and < 1Mb) and I get the following messages after processing around 500 files

**message -1**
*The buffer manager failed a memory allocation call for 76480000 bytes, but was unable to swap out any buffers to relieve memory pressure. 3 buffers were considered and 3 were locked. Either not enough memory is available to the pipeline because not enough are installed, other processes were using it, or too many buffers are locked.*

**message -2**
*Buffer manager allocated 0 megabyte(s) in 0 physical buffer(s).*

**message -3**
*The system reports 64 percent memory load. There are 68718374912 bytes of physical memory with 24701116416 bytes free. There are 2147352576 bytes of virtual memory with 49799168 bytes free. The paging file has 77308309504 bytes with 33875689472 bytes free.*

It seems like SSIS is not cleaning the virtual memory after a file is processed/loaded and when it reaches its limit, the Package fails because of insufficient resources. I cannot change resource allocation because the server is shared.

The first thing I tried was to execute the Package task with **ExecuteOutOfProcess** = True but I get lots of other errors (connection, logging, etc) which are very difficult to identify because debugging is not possible anymore when starting the package via Ms Visual Studio. Besides, I'm not sure parallel processing is a good idea as all files will be loaded to the same SQL table

The (sub-)package seems to be executed with a different user (?) that isn't allowed to use one of the connection manager (csv file or SQl db).
I also have the feeling that parameter binding is not functioning well anymore

**message**
*Executing the query "" failed with the following error: "Unable to acquire a managed connection.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.*

I also played with **AutoAdjustBuffersize** = True or False , reduced **DefaultBufferSize** to the minimum of 1048576. It changes the number of files that can be loaded but it still fails at some point with the same error.

Could anyone help me on that please?

Comment: do you get error in design mode or run with agent service?

Comment: With ExecuteOutOfProcess = False, I get always those error message 1 to 3

Comment: ExecuteOutOfProcess = True, I get different error message when running in design mode than with the agent (in design mode: Error 0x80040154. Failed to create an instance of empty child package. The Distributed Component Object Model (DCOM) configuration or the installation of SQL Server Integration Services, may be corrupted on your machine // with agent: [...] Unable to acquire a managed connection [...])

Comment: Have you tried moving that data flow out of the sub package and into the main package, inside the for each loop?

Comment: Hi Simon, I didn't because the subpackage to be launched is different based on the source file (different folder and source file) so I use the "packagename" as parameter

Comment: in the "Execute Package task" properties, I added Expression PackageName = @[User::PackageName] and it works fine

Comment: You can try to use **Bulk Insert** Task in Control Flow instead of the DFT .

Comment: I haven't because I have a few derived columns and data conversion fields that are not allowed via Bulk Insert, I was hoping that someone bumped into the same issue than I have